# why the command : rosrun libuvc_camera followed by UVCCamera.cfg not the uvccamera_node?

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:
I'm new to ROS system, and i have a problem when using the libuvc_camera package;
below are my steps:

1. Firstly,  clone the libuvc_camera from  https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros
2. commands in the consol : cd libuvc_camera ;  mkdir build;  cd build;  cmake .. ; make ; sudo make install
3. commands:  source devel/setup.bash
4. then if i run the command:  rosrun libuvc_camera  camera_node;  it display messages : couldn't found executable file camera_node in libuvc_camera ; found  libuvc_camera/build/devel/lib/libuvc_camera/camera_node  but it is  not a executable file;
   and when i use the tab; it display commands: rosrun libuvc_camera UVCCamera.cfg
   can somebody tell me what is the problem ? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214188/why-the-command-:-rosrun-libuvc_camera-followed-by-uvccamera.cfg-not-the-uvccamera_node?/) by [lychenpan2@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/23278/lychenpan2@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you should have done more like:

- create the workspace folder
- create src folder inside workspace
- clone into src folder
- execute catkin_make in workspace folder

and before the last one you could install the needed dependencies as seen here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/75241/install-ros-dependencies-from-apt/

Btw you should also be able to install it by package manager I guess
it should be just `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-libuvc-camera`

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lychenpan2@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/23278/lychenpan2@gmail.com/) on 2015-07-23**:
Thanks very much;  i have done what you suggest; and the workspace build successfully.
Now i want to run the camera_node in the libuvc_camera package, and manual its focus absolute;
Can you please give me some more suggestions?
Thanks so much!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-23**:
I guess you should create a new question for that. Cause having an error and making it run and specific settings are completely different things.

**Comment by [lychenpan2@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/23278/lychenpan2@gmail.com/) on 2015-07-23**:
yes, you are right !  thanks!

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-24**:
You're welcome ;-)